# Accessing JSON data through API with js

Tags: javascript, json, web

WHY! Why is this not working. I am using the weatherbit api, and trying to simply get the uv index. Mind you, in a browser the proper link displays all the information but I can not get it to work through js, putting it through to a div.
I replaced the actual request data with (nameOfData) for privacy, I assure you that there is no problem with the parameters specific.

```
$getJSON('https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?lat=(Lat)&lon=(Lon)&key=(Key)', function(data) {
    // JSON result in `data` variable
    $(".UV").html(data.data[1].uv);
});
```

Please help.

Comment: `$getJSON` should have a dot `$.getJSON`. You can also use `.fail` method to get any errors - see the docs: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ -- Impossible to help you more without more info

Comment: Like Jamiec said, if the $.getJSON doesn't solve your issue we need more code to work with, only showing us the call won't get us anywhere.

Comment: That is the only js code for the functionality, so it is not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

It is failing because you need an API key.  Using the URL in the address bar of a browser does not have that restriction.

Sometimes a workaround in this case is to use a proxy on a server.  Your code queries the server, and the server mimics a browser. It depends on the web service how you will fare.

Comment: I do have a url key, like I said.  And in the url the link does not work without the key, regardless.

Comment: If it is working for you, then post what `data.data[1].uv` returns.  And add `.fail(e=>console.error(e))` to your code, too.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with async, somehow.

```
async function getData(){
let response = await fetch(weatherbitApi);
let data = await response.json()
return data;
}
getData().then (data =>
console.log(data.data[0]));
```